# Angular 4: Multiple clicks displays API (get) data array more than one time in SPA

Tags: html, angular, api, http, typescript

I've been searching for som JS/TS/angular solutions the while week, but i can't solve this issue.

I get my data from a restAPI, subscribe to it, and push it into an array.
The array is then displayed by a *ngFor-loop in my HTML.
If i click repeatedly many times on the get-method, the data is displayed on the page multiple times.

Service:

```
 return this.http
      .get(`${this.apiUrl}/stories`, { params: params, headers: headers })
      .map((res: Response) => {
        //console.log(response);
        console.log("params: " + params);
        const data = res.json();
        return data;
      });
  })
```

Component:

```
  this.storiesService.getStories(this.page, this.hits, this.feed)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
            this.hitsArray.push.apply(this.hitsArray, data.hits)
            console.log(this.hitsArray)
          }
    })
}
```

I clear the array, when the user clicks the get-method:

```
this.hitsArray = [];
```

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let story of hitsArray | filter:term:'story'">
```

The object's in the array i then easily set throughout the page:

```
{{story.*OBJECT*}}
```

How should i solve this the most optimal way?
NB: The reason why i made the data pushed into an array, is because i made a lazy scrolling function, that pushes more data from the API into the array, as the user is scrolling.

Comment: Not related, but worth a read :) https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: I know about this :) I've just made this a temporary solution, as i had issues having a non-pipe filter. Any suggestions on doing this is angular 4 is highly appreciated too my friend.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a separate way of putting the results into your array depending on if you clicked the button or if you are scrolling. Have the response push into the array only when you're doing the 'GET' from the scroll action, if your 'GET' is from pushing the button then always set the array equal to your result instead of pushing it.

Comment: Hmm, it might work, but im 90% sure i already tried that - ill work a solution and get back to you. Thank you!